# Vue Value computed from props is undefined when prop is dynamically set with Vuex getter

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I've build a small component for a matrialdesign-like switch. The status of the switch can be set with 'active' property. To toggle the status I use a computed value, because props can't be changed.

If I use the component tag with hardcoded 'active' prop it works. 
If I use a vuex getter to set the prop, the prop get's the right value, but the computed is 'undefined'.

Here the component:

```
<template>
    <div class="flex items-center">
        <div class="flex h-6 rounded-full shadow w-12 cursor-pointer" :class="status" @click="toggle">
            <div class="flex h-6 rounded-full shadow w-6 bg-blue-500">
                <slot></slot>
            </div>
        </div>
        <label class="m-0 ml-2 text-lg normal-case">{{label}}</label>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default{
        props:{
            active: Boolean,
            label: String
        },
        data() {
            return { isActive: this.active }
        },
        computed:{
            status(){

                return this.isActive ? 'justify-end bg-success' : 'justify-start bg-primary';
            }
        },
        methods:{
            toggle(){
                this.isActive = !this.isActive;
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

This works:

```
<toggle label="Foo" active="true">Foo</toggle>
```

This doesn't:

```
<toggle label="Foo" :active="this.$store.getters.FooStatus">Foo</toggle>
```

In Vue Devtools I can see that active is true/false depending on FooStatus, but isActive is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Two things I noticed:

- In the first use case, you are setting the `active` prop to the string value `true`. You should use `:active="true"` or better yet only `active` without an argument.
- In the second use case you shouldn’t use `this`, as the template is already evaluated with all properties, methods, etc. in the local scope. I.e. it should only be

```
:active="$store.getters.FooStatus"
```

The reason, why the change is not propagated might be, because the property is not reactive. This happens for example, if the initial value from vuex passed to `:active` is `undefined`. So you should define a default value:

```
active: {
  default: false,
  type: Boolean
}
```

Alternatively you can assign a proper value to the data field:

```
data() {
  return {
    isActive: Boolean(this.active)
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code as you suggested and now isActive is false regardless of the active property is true or false. You're right, it really looks like the initial value from Vuex is undefined. And for some reason isActive doesn't update upon change of active. So my "quick&dirty" solution is adding a watch on active:

```
 watch: {
    active: function active() {
      this.isActive = Boolean(this.active);
    }
  }
```